# Disable windows update on virtual machine (Hyper-v)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, hyper-v

I have Win 10 running on a VM on Hyper-V, on my server (Windows 10).
I disable the Windows update from the services on the virtual machine.
The server where the virtual machine is installed must restart itself every 2 days.
After restart, the windows update settings on the virtual server has automatically changing as Manual.

I couldn't figure why is doing this. How can I completely disable to windows update on virtual server ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 , especially later versions, turn Updates on and keep them on. So there is really no way to accomplish what you want. You must stay up to date